# TextView not getting updated in ProgressBar

Tags: android

I am trying to update the text of TextView on button click after the spinner progressbar is finished.

```
public void launchRingDialog(View view) {

        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading File ...", true);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String text;
                    int build_num = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    Set buildNumbers = getSharedPreferenceData(build_numbers);
                    boolean result = isPresent(buildNumbers,
                            build_num);
                    if (result) {
                        text = "Present";
                    } else {
                        text = "Not Present";
                    }
                    //Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Text After button click");
                    System.out.println(text);

                     TextView compliance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compliance);
                    compliance.setText(text);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.download_file) {
            System.out.println("Inside button click");
            launchRingDialog(v);
       }
 }
```

In onCreate, I check the build number and it sets the text to "Present". But when I do button click, sharedPreference file gets changed and I check for the current build number which returns "Not Present, which is not getting reflected in the TextView.

Is threading creating a problem here?

Comment: This is probably causing a problem `catch (Exception e) {}` put a log there and I'm sure you'll see you are getting an exception. `.setText()` should be inside a `runOnUiThread()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to call the method compliance.setText(text) from another thread. This isn't allowed on Android. For what you're trying to do, you should really be using an AsyncTask instead of launching your own thread. Something like this:

```
public void launchRingDialog(View view) {

        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading File ...", true);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                String text;
                int build_num = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                Set buildNumbers = getSharedPreferenceData(build_numbers);
                boolean result = isPresent(buildNumbers,
                        build_num);
                if (result) {
                    text = "Present";
                } else {
                    text = "Not Present";
                }

                return text;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                TextView compliance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compliance);
                compliance.setText(s);
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.download_file) {
            System.out.println("Inside button click");
            launchRingDialog(v);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I assume that if I ever have to use multithreading to update some elements, I have to use AsyncTask and not my own thread?

Comment: Also, I am getting 11-05 13:11:22.220: I/Choreographer(1928): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
and the spinner taking too much time to exit. Any reason for that? I have to tap outside the dialog to exit the spinner.

Comment: You can use the regular Thread class as well. But, the problem with that, is that you'll have to do some extra work to make sure your app doesn't crash. You'll have to use a Handler that was instanciated on the UI thread and send a message to that whenever you want to manipulate your UI components. For this very reason, they created AsyncTask which is much much simpler to use. I've found very few special instances where I would want to create my own threads from scratch

Comment: About your second question, not sure why the dialog doesn't dismiss automatically. Try placing a breakpoint in the onPostExecute method and see if dismiss() is being called. Also, why are you instanciating the TextView every time the thread finishes? Why don't you instanciate it once in onCreate() and keep a class level reference to it. Then you just keep calling setText() on it to your heart's content